# logback logs always hibernate query having show_sql to false

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, logback

Having:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="ERROR">
    </logger>
```

on my logback.xml I would expected don't see logs as:

```
fromLogback 2015-03-17 14:20:56,967 39427 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select statsitemi0_.itemId as itemId1_54_, statsitemi0_.companyId as companyI2_54_, statsitemi0_.createDate as
```

As you can see, first is printed "fromLogback" that is because my appender looks like:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>fromLogback %d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

But hibernate debug level seems to be active yet, because I can see all the queries. I have the property hibernate.show_sql=false

```
sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",propertiesUtil.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
```

Only for be sure I print all properties of hibernate when I build the session factory and I see the value of show_sql is properly set to false.

Why I'm still seeing debug logs of hibernate??

Updated:
If I use  on my logback.xml I can see these logs on startup:

```
16:06:04,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to ERROR
16:06:04,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl] to ERROR
16:06:04,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
16:06:04,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:06:04,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
```

and some lines after:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select propertyim0_.key_ as...
```

I have not logback-test.xml
My logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/liferay.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!--<appender name="FILE_CACHE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">-->
        <!--<file>${catalina.base}/logs/cache.log</file>-->
        <!--<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">-->
            <!--<fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/cache.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash; 30 días de historia &ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>-->
        <!--</rollingPolicy>-->

        <!--<encoder>-->
            <!--<charset>UTF-8</charset>-->
            <!--<pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>-->
        <!--</encoder>-->
    <!--</appender>-->

    <appender name="ACCESSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/portlet-shnm-access.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.shn.mkt" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>

    <logger name="com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <!--<appender-ref ref="ACCESSLOG"/>-->
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Note that I'm using Spring Boot, but for the specifications of the project I can not use application.properties or application.yml right now, so I've expected that using my own logback.xml were enough.

Comment: Post your `logback.xml`, and don't you have a `logback-test.xml` in your classpath? Cause its priority precedes `logback.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file setenv.sh of tomcat had:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=worker,backoffice -Ddebug -Xms128m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

`-Ddebug` of Spring Boot was the cause... sorry for all the noise.